# On a planet with 99% humidity all of the time, how would human skin evolve?

Tags: planets, evolution, environment, climate, anatomy

This world has an incredibly high humidity rate all year round and I'm curious as to what - if any - evolutional changes might occur in human skin. Would it just be less porous or would there be a more drastic effect?

edit: humidity might not have been the right way to describe this. I really mean a planet where the air has an incredibly high moisture content and sort of exists as a vapour.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There is a problem with your setting because 99% humidity is not a fixed value.  There 99% humidity is a lot more water vapor if it's 38 Celsius than when it's 99% at 18 Celsius (if you travel to anywhere in the world where it is known for humidity, you can almost set your watch by the rain, which occurs almost daily after the heat of the day breaks (typically around 1500-1700 local time)).  A slight drop in air temperature will cause 99% humid air to become 100% humid and at that point, the water vapor becomes a precipitate.

Comment: To go off my last comment, sweating is just as an effective means of cooling in 99% humidity in Miami, Florida in the July as it is at 99% humidity in Gnome, Alaska in January.  The only difference is that not being able to cool off in Gnome, Alaska in January is the exact opposite of a problem.

Comment: All that said, lots of other cooling methods exist that do not involve humidity (rabbit's ears are used to cool their bodies, for example).

Comment: With 99% humidity lungs do not work. You be drowned by mucus wich will be diluted by air moisure.

Comment: considering it is physically impossible for the air of an entire planet to have 99% humidity, the answer depends on whatever magic you are using.

Comment: "Has an incredibly high moisture content and sort of exists as a vapour" is kind of a contradiction, because 100% humid air (which is pretty common on Earth) _is_ a vapor, and the only way to get the moisture content even higher is to add fog, and that makes the air not a vapor any more. I'm guessing that what you're after is air with a very large amount of suspended liquid water (which is to say, fog).

Comment: @Kamitergh I've been in a 99% humidity environment hundreds of times (running a hot shower in a bathroom will do the trick), and so far, I've survived every single time.

Comment: @Kamitergh that is only true if the air temperature is higher than body temperature.

Comment: Tanner Sweet: really? want to see You shower. Mostly shower can go up to 80% humidity. Look at Miroslav Cekon from Adams Research Centre studies. In some cases like at United Kingdom, very hot water and more than 1 hour shower You can go up to 95% - in theory. In practice going over 90% is very hard due to air exchange. 
John - not only. Mucus will get moisure from air and be diluted. Even not diluted is hard to be removed from body.

Comment: @Kamitergh It looks to me like Cekon has at least 69 published papers; which one in particular should I look at?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With information provided, your answer could go either way. Nature follows the path of least resistance in most all cases. Humans being mammals one possible route is  they might lose their sweat glands and grow short and thick, but sparse hair over their entire body to wick away excess moisture. morphology may change, meaning spaces like spaces between toes may disappear preventing places for fungus to take hold. stance may be altered to accommodate a wide space at the groin to eliminate the same or internalise sexual organs with a cloaca. Ears may begin to shrink to thwart infections, eyes may grow larger to capture more light.

All of this assumes evolution without interference from modern tech to mitigate the evolutionary process.

Comment: What's the reasoning for "eyes may grow larger to capture more light" as a consequence of humidity?

Comment: @nanoman just assumed a possible dark humid and gloomy jungle

Answer (score 8):

1. **No cooling by sweating.**

Humans cool off by sweating.  In 99% humidity sweat does not evaporate so that will not work.  The sweat glands responsible for putting out water to cool us will no longer have an adaptive functon.

2. **Greasier**.  A layer of oil on skin prevents water ingress.  Long distance swimmers grease their bodies to augment the oil layer.  Hippos accomplish this with a greasy pink skin secretion.  Your people would be greasy, and possibly pink.
3. **Redundant skin folds.**  Since sweating is not useful, your people must cool off some other way - and I am assuming a place with 99% humidity is pretty warm.  I assert they would do so by increasing surface area.  They would have many redundant skin folds exposed to the breeze.  They would look much like this Shar-pei dog.  But bipedal I am sure.

[image: shar pei puppy]

[source](https://www.facebook.com/TOPSharPei/posts/quality-chinese-shar-pei-puppies-with-pcci-papers-health-recordsheavy-wrinkled-m/2981425378747760/)

Also greasy and pink; see #2.

Comment: forget skin you would literally drown in your own lungs anytime the air was warmer than your body temperature.

Comment: The creatures in this aren't human, they have different airways. I just used human skin as a sort of baseline to try figure out what kind of phenotypes the environment would produce

Comment: I’m confused by the drowning comments. I’ve been in steam plants where the temperature in places were well over 100 F and 100 percent. Or in the Persian Gulf with  100 % humidity and over 100 F and breathing didn’t seem to be a problem, I thought the issue was core body temperature. Or is there a different concern?

Comment: @UVPhoton - it is easy to get overheated in such environments as surely you recognized when you were there but there is no literal drowning in lungs.  Lungs are humid places too.  Gas exchange works in the humidity.

Comment: In theory, if you inhaled maximally humid air at temperatures over your body temperature, the air would cool when entering your body and water would be forced out of the air into your lungs. I don't know about in practice; the extreme situations where more than a minimal amount of water gets forced into the lungs are very dangerous for simply causing excess body heat.

Comment: @prosfilaes - hmm.  That makes sense as regards the physics.  Some would condense out in the nose and large airways but you could get some in the lung.  Maybe John was right.  no.... couldn't be.  Maybe just this once.

Comment: @Willk it actually happens in some caves, humans can only enter in cooling suits to keep their lungs from filling up with fluid, very few places on earth can maintain high humidity and excessive temperature for any amount of time because of day night cycles, but a few caves manage it. giant crystal cave is one it averages 100% relative humidity and 58 C, it takes about 10 minutes to start drowning. its not that your lungs so much as the AIR in your lungs is cooler so you get dew formation and the lungs have a lot of surface for it to happen on and the water quickly adds up.